# Blog page with out favicon

Tags: bug, blog, favicon

I clicked the BLOG link listed in the Stack Exchange side bar. The page opened with out the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

[image: Blog with out favicon]

Comment: There is a favicon, but it's just a [completely transparent 16x16 image](https://stackoverflow.blog/favicon.ico)...

Comment: What? I thought people liked transparency from a company? ;P